# How do I figure out the "usblp0"

Tags: drivers, usb, printing

I'm trying to troubleshoot a printer... some people online have had luck printing using this command:

```
echo test > /dev/usblp0
```

But it doesn't work for me.

if I do "lsusb" I do see the printer:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04b8:0202 Seiko Epson Corp. Receipt Printer M129C/TM-T70
```

How do I figure out the `/dev/usblp0` command to test?

Comment: What is the result of running `ls /dev/usb*` in a terminal?

Comment: Rather than `echo >/dev/whatever`, which is the Hard Way, use The Easy Way: CUPS (Common Unix Printing System). Ensure `cupsd` is running (`sudo service cups start`), then point your brower at `localhost:631` click on the `Administration` tab, and add/modify your printer